# How would I stop a ball from moving off the screen?

Tags: java

so basically when i use my arrow keys this red ball will move, but I can move it off the screen. How could I make it so that the ball wouldn't be able to move pass the border?

I was thinking about doing something like detecting if the position of the ball was >= the edge of the screen then it would respawn at like the middle, but wasn't sure how I should implement it.

```
//Name: anon   Date:
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import java.awt.image.*;
  
      private class Key extends KeyAdapter
      { 
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
         {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) //arrow key 
               pd.setY( pd.getY()-10);
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
               pd.setY( pd.getY()+10);
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
               pd.setX( pd.getX()-10);
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
               pd.setX( pd.getX()+10);
               
            
            
               
          }
          
       }
```

Comment: By checking the position of the ball and seeing if it's >= the edge of the screen. What's the specific issue? Knowing the screen bounds? (Unrelated, but you likely want to check the *edge* of the ball, not its center.)

Comment: so the screen bounds in (408,438) 
would I do it like this?
if pd.getX >= 408 and pd.getY >= 438 then
pd.setX(350);
pd.setY(350);

Comment: If you simply want to stop the ball leaving the screen, and know it's radius to be r, something like if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP & pd.getY > r) to stop ball moving up at top of screen or if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN & pd.getY < 438 - r) to stop ball at bottom. I may be mistaken using getY, could be getX, but I'm sure you get the drift.

Answer (score 1):

How about checking if the x coordinate plus the radius of the circle is out of bounds and then do the same for the y coordinate?

```java
Point circleCenter;
int radius;

int screenW;
int screenH;

if (circleCenter.x + radius > screenW)
    circleCenter.x = screenW - radius;

if (circleCenter.x - radius < 0)
    circleCenter.x = 0 + radius;

if (circleCenter.y + radius > screenH)
    circleCenter.y = screenH - radius;

if (circleCenter.y - radius < 0)
    circleCenter.y = 0 + radius;
```